What is the best practice to calculate global frequency of list of elements with exact orders in python within multiple pandas dataframe?
Let's say I have the following datafarme df1 corresponding to user1:
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|      Models       |  MAE  |  MSE   | RMSE  | MAPE  | R² score |  Runtime [ms]  |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
| LinearRegression  | 4.906 | 27.784 | 5.271 | 0.405 |  -6.917  | 0:00:43.387145 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|   Random Forest   | 2.739 | 10.239 |  3.2  | 0.231 |  -1.917  | 0:28:11.761681 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|      XGBoost      | 2.826 | 10.898 | 3.301 | 0.234 |  -2.105  | 0:03:58.883474 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|   MLPRegressor    | 5.234 | 30.924 | 5.561 | 0.43  |  -7.812  | 0:01:44.252276 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|        SVR        | 5.061 | 29.301 | 5.413 | 0.417 |  -7.349  | 0:04:52.754769 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
| CatBoostRegressor | 2.454 | 8.823  | 2.97  | 0.201 |  -1.514  | 0:19:36.925169 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|   LGBMRegressor   | 2.76  | 10.204 | 3.194 | 0.231 |  -1.907  | 0:04:51.223103 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+


+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Rank         |                                                          MAE                                             | 
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Top models(sorted)| ["CatBoostRegressor","RandomForest","LGBMRegressor", "XGBoost","LinearRegression","SVR","MLPRegressor"]  |  
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I have following datafarme df2 corresponding to user2:
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|      Models       |  MAE  |  MSE   | RMSE  | MAPE  | R² score |  Runtime [ms]  |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
| LinearRegression  | 4.575 | 24.809 | 4.981 | 0.377 |  -6.079  | 0:00:45.055854 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|   Random Forest   | 2.345 | 8.065  | 2.84  | 0.199 |  -1.301  | 0:10:55.468473 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|      XGBoost      | 2.129 | 7.217  | 2.686 | 0.179 |  -1.059  | 0:01:01.575033 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|   MLPRegressor    | 4.414 | 23.477 | 4.845 | 0.363 |  -5.699  | 0:00:31.231719 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|        SVR        | 4.353 | 22.826 | 4.778 | 0.357 |  -5.513  | 0:02:12.258870 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
| CatBoostRegressor | 2.281 | 7.671  | 2.77  | 0.189 |  -1.189  | 0:08:16.526615 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|   LGBMRegressor   | 2.511 |  9.18  | 3.03  | 0.212 |  -1.619  | 0:15:25.084937 |
+-------------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+


+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Rank         |                                                          MAE                                             | 
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Top models(sorted)| ["XGBoost","CatBoostRegressor","RandomForest","LGBMRegressor","LinearRegression","SVR","MLPRegressor"]  |  
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Let's say I have more datafarmes df1000 corresponding to user1000.
Problem statement: I want to count how often each ranking order occurs across all users (for a given metric). (And then, sort the ranking orders by their counts, and, additionally, compute the percentage of how often each particular ranking order occurs (based on the counts).)
I want to rank Models result (sorted over a specific column (e.g. MAE ) iteratively and return the frequency of top models over all dfs (df1 till df1000). so this is not something I can easily reach using the:
df["category"].value_counts()

we are interested in computing absolute\relative frequencies in final ranked table in expected output.
so definitely I need to transform and add the list of sorted models' names that'd be a list of strings.
Possible transformation or aggregation stages from my understanding:

take each df and create the list of sorted model names based desired column or metric:
['model2','model7', 'model6', 'model5', 'model4', 'model3', 'model1' ]
including the name of Users in the final transformed dataframe could also be useful (however I did not mention it in the following table in the expected output.)
computing absolute\relative frequencies and return as counts and freq(%) in final table

Expected output:
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+
|      Rank         |                                                    MAE                                                  |counts  |freq(%)  |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+
| Top models(sorted)| ["CatBoostRegressor","RandomForest","LGBMRegressor", "XGBoost","LinearRegression","SVR","MLPRegressor"]   | 70     |   65%   |
| Top models(sorted)| ["XGBoost","CatBoostRegressor","RandomForest","LGBMRegressor","LinearRegression","SVR","MLPRegressor"]   | 20     |   12%   |
| Top models(sorted)|                                             ....                                                  | ....     |   ....  |
....
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+

I also was thinking maybe I can use Natural Language Processing (NLP) methods called TF-IDF to handle this problem using:
# import required module
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


Potentially related posts I have checked:

How can I compute a histogram (frequency table) for a single Series?
Count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column
Efficient way to get frequency of elements in a pandas column of lists
Calculate Frequency of item in list
Get the frequency of individual items in a list of each row of a column in a dataframe
count the frequency of elements in list of lists in Python
What's the best alternative to using lists as elements in a pandas dataframe?
pandas - create dataframe with counts and frequency of elements
Python: Calculate PMF for List in Pandas Dataframe
Frequency plot of a Pandas Dataframe
python & pandas - How to calculate frequency under conditions in columns in DataFrame?


I am not sure I understood what your output is expected to contain. Can you explain each column in the output? Also it would help if you can expand the "Problem statement" part to include the exact steps you would take as a human to do this and then we can think about how to translate that logic into calling libraries.

This is logic: I have experimented with several ML models over 1000 users and returned ML models' results over different error metrics (e.g. MAE, etc) for each user as df1... df1000. I'm Interested in finding an answer to this question what the top models are ?  I think the best translation is I rank, which means calculating the absolute\relative frequencies shown as counts and freq(%) of top models (sorted based on i.e. MAE). like ['model2','model7', 'model6', 'model5', 'model4', 'model3', 'model1' ] repeated as top frequent models for 70% of users.

So in your example output, ["CatBoostRegressor","RandomForest","LGBMRegressor", "XGBoost","LinearRegression","SVR","MLPRegressor"] was present in exactly that order when sorted by MAE, for 70% of the users?

What the top models are ?
A simpler and more logic approach would be to concat all those dataframes.
Once this dataframe is created, makes aggregations such as groupby -> median/mean. You can even compte stats in each group such as frequency.
At this stage you do have metrics to evaluate which models are globally top tier or not

@SachinHosmani  in this example based on results of dataframes ( including df1 and other 69 dfs corresponding to user 1  and other 69 other users sorted on metric\column MAE they had exactly this order:  ["CatBoostRegressor","RandomForest","LGBMRegressor", "XGBoost","LinearRegression","SVR","MLPRegressor"]

@imM4TT thanks for your comment. your approach sounds good to me. Can you offer your solution? I can add reproducible dfs for limited users' models' results so that you can propose a solution that can achieve the main goal: Which models are globally top tier. The important is how we concat the dfs (before do we need to sort the results bcz exact order of top models matters) or do we sort during groupbying?

@imM4TT  I think after edited by me and another colleagues the question is clear 100% (using right keywords in content) now and would be nice to vote to re-open! It is scientific question especially for data scientists experiment on multiple models over large number of users/instances.

Does this work?
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# I've left out the other metrics because they are irrelevant to your question, but you can add them
data1 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.906, 2.739, 2.826, 5.234, 5.061, 2.454, 2.76]
}
data2 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.575, 2.345, 2.129, 4.414, 4.353, 2.281, 2.511]
}
data3 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.575, 2.345, 2.129, 4.414, 4.353, 2.281, 2.511]
}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# add your 1000 data frames here if you want
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]

concatenated_models_list = []

for df in dataframes:
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='MAE', ascending=False)
    # Concatenate the sorted-by-MAE model names into one string, so that
    # you can group by it as a key later
    concatenated_models = ','.join(df_sorted['Models'].tolist())
    concatenated_models_list.append(concatenated_models)

# Union everything into a single dataframe
union_df = pd.DataFrame(concatenated_models_list, columns=['Top models(sorted)'])

grouped_df = union_df['Top models(sorted)'].value_counts().reset_index()
grouped_df.columns = ['Top models(sorted)', 'count']

grouped_df['freq(%)'] = (grouped_df['count'] / len(dataframes)) * 100

grouped_df


Output
Top models(sorted)  count   freq(%)
LinearRegression,MLPRegressor,SVR,LGBMRegresso...   2   66.666667
MLPRegressor,SVR,LinearRegression,XGBoost,LGBM...   1   33.333333


Thanks for your solution. looks good!

would you vote to re-open question to give me a chance to select answer?

It doesn't seem like the question has been closed.

Or at least I can't see any option to vote for reopening the question.

IIUC, to get your proposed result you can use this approach:

Sort each dataframe by the desired metric, then concatenate all the strings in column 'Models' into a single string. (list is not hashable, so you won't be able to count it as easily.)
Use the concatenated string to create a new dataframe and append it to out_list.
concat all the dataframes in out_list, then get count and frequency.

metric = "MAE"

in_list = [df1, df2]  # list with all the dataframes
out_list = [
    pd.DataFrame(
        [["Top models(sorted)", df.sort_values(metric)["Models"].str.cat(sep=",")]],
        columns=["Rank", metric],
    )
    for df in in_list
]

out = pd.concat(out_list).value_counts().reset_index(name="count")
out["freq(%)"] = out["count"] / out["count"].sum() * 100

                 Rank                                                MAE  count  freq(%)
0  Top models(sorted)  CatBoostRegressor,Random Forest,LGBMRegressor,...      1     50.0
1  Top models(sorted)  XGBoost,CatBoostRegressor,Random Forest,LGBMRe...      1     50.0


Although to rank the models maybe a more sensible approach would be to concatenate all the dataframes, group by Models and get the sum for all Users.
in_list = [df1, df2]  # list with all the dataframes
out = pd.concat([df.assign(user=i) for i, df in enumerate(in_list)])
out = out.groupby("Models")["MAE"].sum().sort_values()

Models
CatBoostRegressor    4.735
XGBoost              4.955
Random Forest        5.084
LGBMRegressor        5.271
SVR                  9.414
LinearRegression     9.481
MLPRegressor         9.648
Name: MAE, dtype: float64


Thanks for your solution. looks good and thanks for your remark.

would you vote to re-open question to give me a chance to select answer?
